# Error 204: No Content error in Headers column of Network

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, reactjs, backend

Here is my frontend code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Navbar from "../Navbar/Navbar";
import Axios from "axios"; //axios library to make requests to api
import "./Stats.css";
import ReactPaginate from "react-paginate";




function Stats() {
  const [customerList, setCustomerList] = useState([]); //store all that information of the database in a list
  //make an axios request to get information from database
  useEffect(() => {
    Axios.get("http://localhost:3001/customers").then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      setCustomerList(response.data);
    });
  }, []); 

  const updateCustomerContacted = (id) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {contacted: newContacted, id: id}).then((response) => {
      alert("Contacted column updated");
    })
  };
    
  

  //pagination
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
  const customersPerPage = 5 //change this number according to desired number of rows in a page
  const pagesVisited = pageNumber * customersPerPage;
  const displayCustomers = customerList
    .slice(pagesVisited, pagesVisited+customersPerPage)
    .map((val, key ) => {
      const dateStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleDateString('en-CA');
      const timeStr = new Date(val.latest_time_of_visit).toLocaleTimeString();
      const dateTime = `${dateStr} ${timeStr}`;
      return (
        <tr>
          <td>{val.ID}</td>
          <td>{val.name}</td>
          <td>{val.email}</td>
          <td>{val.counts_of_visit}</td>
          <td>{dateTime}</td>
          <td>{val.contacted}</td>
          <div>
          <input type ="text" 
                 placeholder = "Enter Yes/No"
                 onChange={(event) => {
                   setNewContacted(event.target.value);
                 }}
                 ></input>
          <button onClick={() => {updateCustomerContacted(val.id)}}>Edit</button>
          </div>
        </tr>
      );
    })
    //to account for the fact that total number of customers cannot be divided equally among the pages
    const pageCount = Math.ceil(customerList.length / customersPerPage);
    //page change
    const changePage = ({selected}) => {
      setPageNumber(selected);
    }

    //update contacted column
    const [newContacted, setNewContacted] = useState(0);

   
  

  {/*}
    const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(1);
  
    useEffect(() => {
      fetch("/time")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          setCurrentTime(data.time);
        });
    }, []);
  */}
    
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <div className="container">
        {/*}
      <h1>Customer Information</h1>
  */}
      </div>
      <table className="customertable">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>S/N</th>
          <th>Customer Name</th>
          <th>Customer Email</th>
          <th>Counts of Visit</th>
          <th>Latest Time of Visit</th>
          <th>Contacted?</th>
          <th>Actions</th>    
               

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        {displayCustomers} 
        </tbody>
        
      </table>
      <ReactPaginate 
          previousLabel={"Previous"}
          nextLabel={"Next"}
          pageCount={pageCount}
          onPageChange={changePage}
          containerClassName={"paginationBttns"}
          pageLinkClassName={"paginationNumber"}
          previousLinkClassName={"previousBttn"}
          nextLinkClassName={"nextBttn"}
          disabledClassName={"paginationDisabled"}
          activeClassName={"paginationActive"}
        />
    </div>
  );
}

export default Stats;
```

Here is my backend code

```
//set up express server
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
//set up sql server
const mysql = require("mysql");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
//create a variable called db to make your SQL Statements
const db = mysql.createConnection({
  user: "",
  host: "",
  password: "",
  database: "",
});

//GET REQUEST to database to retrieve customers information from database
app.get("/customers", (req, res) => {
  db.query("SELECT * FROM customer_info", (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }
  });
});

//Update customers
app.put("/update", (req, res) => {
  const id = req.body.id
  const contacted = req.body.contacted;
  db.query("UPDATE customer_info SET contacted = ? WHERE ID = ?", [contacted, id], (err,result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err)
    } else {
      res.send(result);
    }

  });
})

//check if backend server is running
app.listen(3001, () => {
  console.log("Your server is running on port 3001");
});
```

In my front end code in this code block

```
  const updateCustomerContacted = (id) => {
    Axios.put("http://localhost:3001/update", {contacted: newContacted, id: id}).then((response) => {
      alert("Contacted column updated");
    })
  };
```

I managed to get the alert dialog up when the edit button is pressed, but mySQL database does not get updated.
On checking the network section upon inspection:

I have a
Request URL: http://localhost:3001/update
Request Method: PUT
Status Code: 200 OK
with request payload: contacted: "Yes"

but another
Request URL: http://localhost:3001/update
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content

How can I update my database?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests this seems relevant. 204 isn't an error. It's just telling you that the OPTIONS request to http://localhost:3001/update responded with an empty response (or one with no content). The OPTIONS request is made to ensure you can make a GET request (CORS).

Comment: Have you tried adding a check to your backend? Under PUT /update method, below `contacted` add `if (!contacted || !id) return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Bad Request' });` then does the response end in 200 or 400?